# Cloudfront 405 error not displaying custom error page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, custom-error-pages

I created custom error page on Cloudfront with HTTP error code **404** and **405**. I pointed the response page path to **private/index.html** hosted in s3 bucket.

[image: custom error pages]

I managed to display a custom error page for 404

[image: 405 Error]

but when I try hitting the Cloudfront domain using **TRACE** method in Postman I'm getting 405 but the custom response page path is not showing. It's still showing the default 405 error by Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFront does not support TRACE method. Please see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_AllowedMethods.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorS3Origin.html#RequestS3HTTPMethods) in AWS documentation.